# Visual studio code detecta mal los atajos de teclado

Tags: vscode

Cuando quiero ejecutar un atajo de teclado por ejemplo `Ctrl+s` para guardar me ejecuta otro comando, ya entré a las configuraciones de asignación de atajos de teclado y cuando quiero asignar una tecla a un comando me detecta otro atajo por ejemplo al presionar `Ctrl+s` me detecta `Ctrl+d`, y esto sólo pasa con Visual Studio Code, con otros editores todo funciona bien.

Comment: ¿Ya checaste que tu teclado esté configurado correctamente? puede que sea un error de que lo tengas por ejemplo en AZERTY en vez de QWERTY, no sé si pueda ser que Visual Studio tenga una configuración independiente.